# Use Jasmine to stub JS callbacks based on argument values

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, nodeunit

I've got a JS method in my node.js app that I want to unit test. It makes several calls to a service method, each time passing that service a callback; the callback accumulates the results.

How can I use Jasmine to stub out the service method so that each time the stub is called, it calls the callback with a response determined by the arguments?

This is (like) the method I'm testing:

```
function methodUnderTest() {

    var result = [];
    var f = function(response) {result.push(response)};

    service_method(arg1, arg2, f);

    service_method(other1, other2, f);

    // Do something with the results...
}
```

I want to specify that when service_method is called with arg1 and arg2, the stub will invoke the f callback with a particular response, and when it is called with other1 and other2, it will invoke that same callback with a different particular response.

I'd consider a different framework, too. (I tried Nodeunit, but didn't get it to do what I wanted.)

Answer (score 15):

You should be able to use the `callFake` spy strategy. In jasmine 2.0 this would look like:

```
describe('methodUnderTest', function () {
  it("collects results from service_method", function() {
    window.service_method = jasmine.createSpy('service_method').and.callFake(function(argument1, argument2, callback) {
      callback([argument1, argument2]);
    });

    arg1 = 1, arg2 = 'hi', other1 = 2, other2 = 'bye';
    expect(methodUnderTest()).toEqual([[1, 'hi'], [2, 'bye']]);
  });
});
```

Where `methodUnderTest` returns the results array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stub it as is, because it's private an internal to the method.

You are testing the wrong thing here.  `methodUnderTest` should be tested by ensuring that the results are properly handled.  Ensuring that `service_method` executes it's callback with specific arguments is another test altogether and should be tested independently.

Now the spec for `methodUnderTest` can simply be about what happens AFTER that callback.  Dont worry if the callbacks work, because you've already tested that elsewhere.  Just worry about what the method does with the results of the callback.

Even if `service_method` is from a library or vendored code you don't directly control, this still applies.  The rule of thumb is to test code YOU yourself write, and trust that other libraries follow the same rule.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not sure you're testing the right thing here, you can use a [spy](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies) and call spy.argsForCall.

```
var Service = function () {
};

Service.service_method = function (callback) {
  someAsyncCall(callback);
};

function methodUnderTest() {

    var result = [];
    var f = function(response) {result.push(response)};

    Service.service_method(arg1, arg2, f);

    Service.service_method(other1, other2, f);

}
```

in your test:

```
it('should test something', function () {
  spyOn(Service, 'service_method');
  methodUnderTest()
  var arg1 = Service.argsForCall[0][0];
  var arg2 = Service.argsForCall[0][1];
  var f = Service.argsForCall[0][2];
  if(arg1==condition1 && arg2==condition2){f(response1)}

});
```

Comment: Both answers here misinterpret my question; I'm wondering why. I really am testing methodUnderTest(); I want to verify that after it makes its calls to its dependencies - in this case,  service_method() - it accumulates the results.

Comment: Ok, as I understand you want to test the inner method f here? But why you wanna mock out service_method(). Isn't it part of your module here. If so don't mock it out.

Comment: No, Andreas - I want to test methodUnderTest(), of course. It depends on service_method(), which, instead of returning a value, invokes a callback. service_method() is what I want to stub. It will call back to f() with the response; I want my mock service_method() to call back to it.

I've successfully used Sinon.JS to stub service_method() and invoke the callback with the stubbed "return" value.